# Template.templatename.rendered can't return any data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I would like to know how can I get the data from mongodb in Template.templatename.rendered function. I tried click event on other template and it's all working fine and return the results i wanted. But what I need is to rendered the chart on load. But I could not get any data from the mongodb.

**//poll.js**

```
    var drawPollChart = function(){

    //returns data on other template methods except for 
    //Template.templatename.rendered
    var dist = getDistinctQuestionId();
    alert('dist:'+dist);
    var data_x =[];
    for(var i=0; i< 1; i++)
    {
          var count = getDataCount(dist[i]);
            var uniq = getDistinctResponseBucket(dist[i]);
            for(var j=0; j<uniq.length; j++)
            {
                //alert('data:' + count[uniq[j]] + ", label:" + uniq[j]);
                data_x.push({
                    data : count[uniq[j]], 
                    label: uniq[j]
                });
            }
    }

Template.pollChart.rendered = function() {
    //can't draw a thing cause can't get any data from mongodb
    drawPollChart();
};
```

Help please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the template is rendered doesn't mean the DB is connected.

Use Meteor.status().status to detect the state of the connection. For example you could wait to render the pollChart-template at all until Meteor.status().status === 'connected'.

Comment: Not only that, but you need to check if the subscription is ready with .ready() method: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe